# How to synchronize computer clock without admin rights

Tags: windows-7, administrator, clock

I have several applications that will not run correctly because my school laptop has the wrong date and time. I can not synchronize it to the internet because this requires admin rights. I can't have my school do it because it's summer vacation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes you can set the clock manually by entering the computer's BIOS setup program when it boots (usually by hitting a special key like DELETE or F2).

Comment: Good to hear, especially since it's often possible to password protect being able to change the BIOS settings, too, but apparently your school didn't do that.

Answer (score -1):

From the "Start" button, choose "Run" and enter "cmd.exe" in the text box.
On the CMD type:

**date**

It will show you the current date of the computer and should allow you to type a new date on this format: *mm-dd-yy*, just type it and press **Enter**

To change the time its the same but instead of the command date type:

**time**

And type *hh:mm:ss*

That should do it.. im not 100% sure it works without admin rights... but give it a try

Comment: I have tried this solution ; unfortunately it requires admin rights