# On a Toshiba laptop, how can I change the machine's time if I cannot log on as an administrator?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop and my uncle possesses the administrator credentials.  How can I change the time without these credentials?

Comment: That's kind of the idea of giving people non-admin accounts… so they cannot override admin settings.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Changing the time requires admin privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to synchronize computer clock without admin rights](http://superuser.com/questions/446076/how-to-synchronize-computer-clock-without-admin-rights)

Comment: he just told me that he did not put it on there

Comment: Not sure that is a duplicate; synchronizing time against a NTP source and setting the time manually are two rather different operations (though the accepted answer looks applicable to this situation as well).

Comment: if he didn't put it on there then is it possible that the computer did that its self???

Comment: cause he said he didnt

Comment: A computer cannot set an Administrator password itself.  A computer cannot do anything, a user has not specifically allowed to happen, so no what you describe is not possible.

Comment: Your uncle said that he didn't *do **what?***  Do you mean that he *gave* you the laptop, intending it to be your property now and into the future, and he didn't mean to give you a restricted account?  Then ask him to give your account administrator privileges, before he forgets his password. Or do you mean that he didn't program the computer to keep track of the time and restrict changing the clock to privileged users?  Because that's the standard behavior for operating systems, so the computer might have come that way (although it didn't "do that itself").

Answer (score 2):

You will need the administrator password. If your uncle didn't set it or doesn't remember it, when I need to reset a forgotten or unknown password for an administrator account on a Microsoft Windows system, I use the [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). You can download the software from [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor, Bootdisk / CD](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

You will need to create a bootable CD or USB flash drive from the [.iso image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file within the zip file you download and then boot the system from the CD or USB flash drive. Once you've done so, you can remove the password for any account on the system. Note that simply copying an executable file to a CD or flash drive as you might usually do to put files on disc/disk is not sufficient. You have to create bootable media so that you can boot from that media rather than booting the system into Windows. You can find instructions for creating a bootable CD in responses to another question posted on this site, [Create Bootable CD from ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/137512/create-bootable-cd-from-iso).

Some systems will boot from a bootable CD or flash drive, if one is available, before booting from an internal drive. Others will attempt to boot from an internal drive first. If that is the case with your laptop, you may need to change a [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)/[UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) setting to configure the system to attempt first to boot from a CD or USB-attached device. To change the setting, if the system won't attempt to first boot from those media, you will need to hit a key or key combination when you restart the system before it boots into Windows. Without knowing the model of Toshiba laptop you have, I don't know what that will be for your system. [With some Toshiba laptops, you can hit F12 to get a boot menu](http://support.moonpoint.com/hardware/pc/bios/) that will allow you to pick the boot device. On others I've had to use `Esc F1`, i.e, the escape key and the F1 function key to get into the BIOS and change the boot order for devices.

There is an overview of the process for resetting an account's password at 
[Offline NT Password & Registry Editor, Walkthrough](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). You can also find other guides for using the tool online, such as [Reset Windows 8.1 password with the free tool ntpasswd](https://4sysops.com/archives/reset-windows-8-1-password-with-the-free-tool-ntpasswd/) at the [4sysops](https://4sysops.com) site. The article explains how you can create a bootable disc, if you don't know how to do so. The author of the article, Michael Pietroforte, also has posted a list of other articles he has written for resetting a forgotten administrator password on a Windows system at [Reset Windows 7 / 8 administrator password](https://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-reset-a-windows-vista-admin-password/)

I haven't used the software on a Microsoft Windows system, and the download page states "More or less tested from NT3.5 up to Windows 8.1, including the server versions like 2003, 2008 and 2012. Also 64 bit windows supported.", so I don't know if it will work on a Windows 10 system, if that is the operating system on the laptop.